ffmpeg trying to fix video with out of sync PTS
I'm working with a mp4 video originally from a livestream, that plays the first three minutes normally then only plays audio. I've had some luck using the setpts filter as I end up with video that lasts 68 minutes of the 73 minutes of audio. However, this results in a desync between video and audio that starts early in the video, and builds throughout. The original video has some duplicate frames as a result of frame drops when originally streamed but I don't see these duplicate frames in the output video from ffmpeg. I'm unsure if the setpts filter is dropping these frames or some other issue is apparent. I'm not experienced with using ffmpeg/trying to fix videos so let me know if there is any more detail I can provide..
input video general info
ffmpeg version 2024-08-18-git-7e5410eadb-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      59. 34.100 / 59. 34.100
  libavcodec     61. 11.100 / 61. 11.100
  libavformat    61.  5.101 / 61.  5.101
  libavdevice    61.  2.100 / 61.  2.100
  libavfilter    10.  2.102 / 10.  2.102
  libswscale      8.  2.100 /  8.  2.100
  libswresample   5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libpostproc    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.26.101
  Duration: 01:13:34.85, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1042 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 20969 kb/s, 623.94 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 97 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
At least one output file must be specified

Frame logs to the input and output videos if helpful.
